# is $select supported when querying ToDoTaskList and ToDoTask in Microsoft GraphAPI

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

I am new to Microsoft Graph API. I am trying to make a call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/todo/lists?$select=displayName,id
```

in Graph Explorer, as I want only get `id` and `displayName` of the `todotasklists` that I have access for.

When I run this in Graph Explorer, I am getting "Bad Request"-400 with error details as below:

```
 "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
            ...
            }
        }
```

I am getting same error when I use `$select` when use endpoint for getting all todoTasks present in a specific ToDoTaskList.

Is `$select` not support for todoTaskList and todoTasks?
I am able to use the `$select` when I make api call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=subject
```

I want only specific information like title and id about todotask to be returned and not all information about todoTask, same with todotasklist.

Comment: Having the same issue more than a year on. It's almost like Microsoft wants me to query *everything* from the APIs just to get one property, wasting their resources and make my application slower in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Now, it looks like `$select` is not supported

```
GET /me/todo/lists?$select=id
```

returns all properties instead only `id`

`GET /me/todo/lists?$select=displayName` (or isOwner, isShared, wellknownListName)

returns Invalid request.